# How to attach an attachment in angular

Tags: angular

My use case is I want to attach the attachment, but when I click on the attach it is refreshing the page.

**File upload.html**

```
<input type="file" class="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload>

                                    <div class="file-upload">

                                        {{fileName || "No file uploaded yet."}}

                                        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="upload-btn" (click)="fileUpload.click()">
                                            <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
```

**File upload.ts**

```
onFileSelected(event) {

    const file:File = event.target.files[0];

    if (file) {

        this.fileName = file.name;

        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("thumbnail", file);

        const upload$ = this.http.post("/api/thumbnail-upload", formData);

        upload$.subscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `form` around a `button`, and you don't use `[formGroup]` on your form or `[type="button"]` on your button, you get the native beahaviour of a form, that post your form and reloads the page.

```html
<input type="file" class="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload>
<div class="file-upload">
  {{fileName || "No file uploaded yet."}}
  <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="upload-btn" (click)="fileUpload.click()">
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="true">attach_file</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please more elaborate by some code on my same use case?

Comment: <button `type="button"` mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="upload-btn" (click)="fileUpload.click()">
                                            <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
                                        </button>